# process-host-perfdata-file or process-service-perfdata-file command doesn't seem to be always triggered

Tags: nagios

Using Nagios 3.5.1 and pnp4nagios 0.6.20 successfully for a moment. Once in a while Nagios simply stop triggering the command process-host-perfdata-file or/and process-service-perfdata-file.

These lead to have perfdata files growing past capacity of process_perfdata.pl.

I have activated debugging in Nagios, pnp4nagios and NPCD. I can't seems to find why Nagios stop moving the file per command line definition.

Any hint on what can be blocking Nagios to operate properly?

Using Nagios and pnp4nagios rpm from Epel repository.

Comment: Have you tried any of the other modes? http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/modes

Comment: @Keith Not yet. Mainly because of the load on the server. I will keep an eye on this.